# How to Have a "Three State" Checkbox / Switch in iOS XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need a checkbox where the user can set the state to 'unset'. Basically, I present the user a form where he can state that he agree with something (true), he doesn't agree with something (false), or he doesn't say anything about it (null / empty / unset). If he set to true or false, I will send data to the server. But if it's in unset state, the server will set the record to null / empty / unset. This is useful for a search where the user can state if he want to search a property which has AC, or doesn't have AC, or both.

How can I do that in XCode for iOS? Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the mock up to help visualize what I'm going for. The solution doesn't have to be exactly like this (doesn't have to be a checkbox), as I know that user usually expect that checkbox only have two values (true, false) only. But this is the closest visualization I can come up with.

[image]

Comment: Asking for libraries or other off-site resources is considered off-topic. In general you should try to find libraries or frameworks like that via googling it. I do not know about any one that would offer such functionality and would guess that *you* have to create the 3-state switch yourself.

Comment: Can you please share the screen? Need to understand how it's presented visually.

Comment: @TechBee I have updated the question with the mock up visual.

Comment: @luk2302 I have already googled it before, and found nothing about it. Thanks.

Comment: btw, Xcode, not XCode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html).

If you need to select any option from the 3 provide then the segment control is best for you. You can customize it according to your design.

Comment: I have seen the UISegmentedControl. This is actually the closest to the solution I have had in mind so far. But it only have a little bit problem: it took too much screen space. But maybe with some tweaks, I can actually use this. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: You can manage its size. If you provide your mockup i may help you.

Comment: thank you for the github. That looks promising. I'm checking it right now. Thanks.

Comment: Sure you can customize it as you want. You can add 3 different option instead of 2